# How to edit category/archive page?

Tags: categories, pages

Basically I want to customize this [page](https://passportpilgrimage.com/category/destinations/albania/) to make it look like this [page](https://passportpilgrimage.com/albania/), however I can only edit text over the featured image with my theme. Is there a way to edit the category/archive page (sorry for my ignorance of wordpress terms)/how would I do that?

I've done very basic html/css but I don't understand the answers on this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235875/how-to-edit-archive-pages-content-inside-wordpress-dashboard)

Comment: You can change the appearance of the category page (list of posts assigned to a given category, e.g. "Albania") by editing the `category.php` file in your active theme.

Comment: Can themes hide the category.php file/could it possibly be named archive.php? I can't find a category.php file in the theme file editor

Comment: In the question you mentioned there is a link to the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview). The way it works is that when displaying, for example, the "**albania**" category, WP will use the first existing file: `category-albania.php` or `category.php` or `archive.php`. You can create a `category.php` by copying the `archive.php` and making changes to the new file. Displaying a single post (your second "page" link) is the responsibility of `single.php` (if exists) or `singular.php`, as you can see in the diagram.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I realized it wasn't possible to create these files without creating a child theme so I just got the Elementor pro plugin which was much easier